What does $x_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ literally mean in this exotic Furstenberg integer topological ring?
Let $(\Bbb{Z}, \tau)$ be the Furstenberg / profinite / coset topological ring structure.  That is topological basis consists of $c\Bbb{Z} + d$ such that $c,d \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $c \neq 0$.
In the usual topological space $\Bbb{R}$ we have an intuitive idea of what $x_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ means by drawing open balls around $a$ that eventually contain the whole sequence tail.
In the case of Furstenberg topology / cosets, what is an alternative definition of $x_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$?
Attempt.
A Furstenberg metric can be taken to be $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ where $|z| = \frac{1}{\max\{ k \in \Bbb{N} : \text{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots, k)\ \mid\ z\}}$ is a norm.
If $d(a, x_n) \lt \frac{1}{k}$, then $\text{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, k+1) \mid (x_n-a)$ i.e that is $\iff x_n = a \mod \text{lcm}(1,2,\dots, k+1)$.
Therefore, a sequence $x_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ in Furstenberg's topology means?
I'm having trouble seeing if this means $x_n$ can start out "random integers" and then "eventually for some $N \in \Bbb{N}$ we have that $x_n\in a + d_n\Bbb{Z}$ such that $d_1 \mid d_2 \mid \dots$" or if it must consist entirely of $x_n \in a + d_n\Bbb{Z}$ for $d_1 \mid d_2 \mid \dots$ such that $d_n \to \infty$.
Any ideas or insights?

What do you mean by "$d_n \to \infty$"? With respect to the usual topology on $\mathbb R$? If you just consider one such $(d_n)n$, this does not suffice, for instance, $(2^n){n \in \mathbb N}$ does not converge to $0$. What you would need is $d_n \to 0$ with respect to the Fürstenberg topology.
Then "$x_n\in a + d_n\Bbb{Z}$" for almost all $n$ is sufficient for convergence, but not necessary: The indices need not be the same.
But it's certainly easier and less confusing to consider just one (but arbitrary) $d \neq 0$ instead of a sequence.

@Ulli yes everything you said is right.  I guess I meant the usual absolute value of $d_n$ increases to infinity.

By definition, $x_n$ converges to $a$ if any open neighborhood of $a$ contains all but finitely many of the $x_n$. It suffices to check this condition on the basis elements for the topology. Basic neighborhoods of $a$ are of the form $a + c\mathbb{Z}$ for integer $c > 0$, so the requirement is that for any positive integer $c$, there exists $N$ such that $c \mid (x_n - a)$ for all $n > N$, where $N$ is allowed to depend on $c$.
As usual, you can ignore finitely many elements of the sequence for the purpose of convergence.

Also, what does your last sentence mean?  "You can ignore..." in what process? Thanks.

Convergence of a sequence only depends on the tail of the sequence, regardless of the topology you are using. This means that ${x_n}{n = 1}^\infty$ converges to $a$ if and only if ${x_n}{n = N}^\infty$ converges to $a$ for some $N \geq 1$.
